# Simba JDBC Driver and Read timed out error BigQuery

Tags: scala, jdbc, google-bigquery, doobie

I'm using Simba JDBC driver for bigquery in a scheduled job. Many times the job works and sometimes it fails because of:

```
sept. 08 12:40:38.307 TRACE 677 com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.BQClient.insertJob: Read timed out
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:472)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:70)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1354)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:963)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:292)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:351)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:754)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:689)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1615)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1512)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1510)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(AccessController.java:795)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1509)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:527)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:334)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse.<init>(NetHttpResponse.java:36)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:149)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1012)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:514)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:455)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:565)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.BQClient.insertJob(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.BQClient.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQSQLExecutor.internalPrepare(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQSQLExecutor.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQDataEngine.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.jdbc41.S41PreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.jdbc42.S42PreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.jdbc42.BQJDBC42ObjectFactory.createPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.JDBCObjectFactory.newPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.SConnection$5.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.SConnection$5.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.SConnection$StatementCreator.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.SConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.SConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.SConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:337)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at doobie.free.KleisliInterpreter$ConnectionInterpreter.$anonfun$prepareStatement$1(kleisliinterpreter.scala:791)
    at doobie.free.KleisliInterpreter.$anonfun$primitive$2(kleisliinterpreter.scala:109)
    at cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$.cats$effect$internals$IORunLoop$$loop(IORunLoop.scala:104)
    at cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$.restartCancelable(IORunLoop.scala:51)
    at cats.effect.internals.IOBracket$BracketStart.run(IOBracket.scala:100)
    at cats.effect.internals.Trampoline.cats$effect$internals$Trampoline$$immediateLoop(Trampoline.scala:67)
    at cats.effect.internals.Trampoline.startLoop(Trampoline.scala:35)
    at cats.effect.internals.TrampolineEC$JVMTrampoline.super$startLoop(TrampolineEC.scala:90)
    at cats.effect.internals.TrampolineEC$JVMTrampoline.$anonfun$startLoop$1(TrampolineEC.scala:90)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:94)
    at cats.effect.internals.TrampolineEC$JVMTrampoline.startLoop(TrampolineEC.scala:90)
    at cats.effect.internals.Trampoline.execute(Trampoline.scala:43)
    at cats.effect.internals.TrampolineEC.execute(TrampolineEC.scala:42)
    at cats.effect.internals.IOBracket$BracketStart.apply(IOBracket.scala:80)
    at cats.effect.internals.IOBracket$BracketStart.apply(IOBracket.scala:58)
    at cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$.cats$effect$internals$IORunLoop$$loop(IORunLoop.scala:183)
    at cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$RestartCallback.signal(IORunLoop.scala:463)
    at cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$RestartCallback.apply(IORunLoop.scala:484)
    at cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$RestartCallback.apply(IORunLoop.scala:422)
    at cats.effect.internals.IOShift$Tick.run(IOShift.scala:36)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

   at com.simba.googlebigquery.dsi.core.impl.DSILogger.logTrace(Unknown Source)
   at com.simba.googlebigquery.support.LogUtilities.logTrace(Unknown Source)
   at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.BQClient.insertJob(Unknown Source)
   at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.BQClient.prepare(Unknown Source)
   at ...
```

It's not possible to set a NetworkTimeout because the driver didn't implement it

```
sept. 08 12:40:18.085 INFO  612 com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.SConnection.SConnection: Driver version is: 01.02.19.1023
sept. 08 12:40:18.085 TRACE 612 com.simba.googlebigquery.dsi.core.impl.DSIConnection.getProperty(170): +++++ enter +++++
sept. 08 12:40:18.085 INFO  612 com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.SConnection.SConnection: Datasource version is: 01.02.19.1023
sept. 08 12:40:18.085 TRACE 612 com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.jdbc41.S41Connection.getNetworkTimeout(): +++++ enter +++++
sept. 08 12:40:18.092 ERROR 612 com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.jdbc41.S41Connection.getNetworkTimeout: [Simba][JDBC](10220) Cette fonctionnalité optionnelle n’est pas prise en charge par le pilote.
java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: [Simba][JDBC](10220) Cette fonctionnalité optionnelle n’est pas prise en charge par le pilote.
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.exceptions.ExceptionConverter.toSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.jdbc41.S41Connection.getNetworkTimeout(Unknown Source)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.getAndSetNetworkTimeout(PoolBase.java:526)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.setupConnection(PoolBase.java:396)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:363)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$100(HikariPool.java:71)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:725)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:711)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

How to set up a connection timeout?
The global timeout we can set with simba driver has no effect (set at 360s -> 6min).

The connection fails ~ 20sec after bq job insertion

```
sept. 08 12:40:18.185 TRACE 677 com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.BQClient.insertJob(GenericData{classInfo=[configuration, etag, id, jobReference, kind, selfLink, statistics, status, user_email], {configuration=GenericData{classInfo=[copy, dryRun, extract, jobTimeoutMs, jobType, labels, load, query], {dryRun=true, query=GenericData{classInfo=[allowLargeResults, clustering, connectionProperties, createDisposition, createSession, defaultDataset, destinationEncryptionConfiguration, destinationTable, flattenResults, maximumBillingTier, maximumBytesBilled, parameterMode, preserveNulls, priority, query, queryParameters, rangePartitioning, schemaUpdateOptions, tableDefinitions, timePartitioning, useLegacySql, useQueryCache, userDefinedFunctionResources, writeDisposition], {parameterMode=POSITIONAL, query=
DECLARE foo INT64;
DECLARE bar INT64;

SET foo = (
    SELECT MIN(table_name) FROM (
        SELECT CAST(table_name AS INT64) AS table_name
        FROM `project.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`
        WHERE creation_time < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL '15' MINUTE)
        ORDER BY 1 DESC
        LIMIT 72
    )
);

SET bar = (
    SELECT CAST(table_name AS INT64)
    FROM `project.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`
    WHERE creation_time < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL '15' MINUTE)
    ORDER BY 1
    DESC LIMIT 1
);

WITH q1 AS (
     SELECT
         cell,
         toto,
         SUM(cell1) AS cells1,
         SUM(cell2) AS cells2
     FROM `project.dataset.*`
     WHERE CAST(_TABLE_SUFFIX AS INT64) BETWEEN foo AND bar
     GROUP BY row
 ),
 q2 AS (
     SELECT
         cell,
         SUM(cells1) AS total_cells1,
         SUM(cells2) AS total_cells2
     FROM q1
     GROUP BY cell
     HAVING total_cells1 > 5000 AND total_cells2 > 0
 )
 SELECT *
 FROM q2 ...
 ;
  , useLegacySql=false}}}}, jobReference=GenericData{classInfo=[jobId, location, projectId], {jobId=SimbaJDBC_Job_f20c577e-5270-44b2-968a-1d449197650e}}}}, "project"):
```

I'm using simba driver 1.2.19.1023
Wrapped in doobie DriverManager 0.10.0
Scala version: 2.13

Answer (score 0):

SocketTimeoutException indicates that the TCP connection is broken. The driver has a retry mechanism on a timeout, and will retry 5 times with exponential backoff (resulting in the error occurring rarely) before throwing the error.

In order to solve this issue, the product team has recently released BigQueryJDBC 1.2.18.1022, where they’ve added additional handling so the driver will retry the query properly on retryable errors until the timeout is reached. Therefore, I would suggest that you update to the 1.12.18 driver version.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer but like it's written in the description (last sentence), we use 1.2.19.1023 version of the driver. And the results are the same

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection string parameter:

`jdbc:bigquery://https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2:443;ProjectId=...;Timeout=3600;LargeResultDataset=_simba_jdbc;`

I fixed that running in a linux server and NiFi 1.14. But I am facing the same problem under windows 10 local instance with NiFi 1.15, both over SimbaJDBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery42_1.2.21.1025.

Comment: Does var `Timeout` mean seconds? or minutes?

Comment: Seconds @YangwookIanJeong